# Can not delete Outlook 2013 mailbox folder

Tags: microsoft-outlook, sync, file-permissions, microsoft-outlook-2013

When I try to delete mailbox folder in the Outlook, it gives this error:

> Cannot delete this folder. Right-click the folder, and then click
>   Properties to check your permissions for the folder. See the folder
>   owner or your administrator to change your permissions. Outlook is
>   synchronizing local changes made to items in the folder. You cannot
>   remove this folder until the synchronization with the server is
>   complete.

But if I check the folder permissions the user has full permissions and is the owner of that folder. Also there is no synchronization process.
How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Did you check if any outlook processes are still running in the task manager? Also do you mean folder on the desktop or folder inside your mailbox?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After searching for a solution I have found this,

Try logging on to outlook web access (OWA webmail) and deleting the folder from there.

After deleting folder via OWA, when I looked outlook, the folder had been already gone.

Comment: Seems to be an Outlook 2013. I have the same problem trying to Empty the Delete Items folder. I only get the error if there are folders underneath it... but just e-mails within Delete Items erase just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Have you deleted multiple folders with the same name? I noted when I did that, the trash folder could only take up to around 20 of them. Once I hit 20 folders of the same name, I began getting that error. Renaming and then deleting worked, or just emptying the trash folder worked.

Comment: I just encountered this. We have a plug-in that removes its working folder when starting up and we had a bug where it was not fully deleting it from the trash. 20 copies later and this bug was encountered.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same thing. However, I am able to left-click and drag the folder in question to the Deleted Items folder, and then empty the Deleted Items folder successfully.

Comment: Ugh. Don't try moving the undeletable folder across mail accounts in OWA.Duplicates of unreadable, undeletable folders ("Your rrequest cannot be completed at this time)? Yes we can.